# HTML / Javascript Check window close and execute function

Tags: javascript, html, function, events

I'm detecting window closed this way, and It works but I can't execute a function.

```
function myFunc(){
   alert("byebye");
}
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    myFunc(); //Error, it doesn't execute
    return "Bye"; //It works, it shows an alert.
};
```

How can I call myFunc when I'm closing a window/tab?

Answer (score 1):

Try this by replacing alert by return.

```
function myFunc(){
   return "byebye";
}
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    myFunc(); //Error, it doesn't execute
    return "Bye"; //It works, it shows an alert.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call functions at the onbeforeunload event, you can only pass a string  that is shown to the user.

Comment: Sorry - I was too fast - you can pass a function, but this function must  return a string. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: What if I want a function to modify the UI instead of showing a message? I'm in trouble with that

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do anything else than showing a message when closing a window.